# calling a function defined in a header file from a Class constructor in C++

Tags: c++, header, lnk2019

I have a header file, let's call it `header1.h` with the definition of a function, let's say `myFunc()` in it. My C++ project has a source file, let's call it `main.cpp` and a header file `main.h`. I have included `header1.h` in the `main.h` and then included `main.h` in `main.cpp`.

In the `main.cpp` I have a class constructor let's call it `MyClass` and I have this code:

```
MyClass:MyClass(...)
.
.
{
  .
  .
  f = myFunc(...);
  .
}
```

when I compile the code I get this error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _myFunc referenced in function
```

What is the reason for this error?

Comment: Have you tried making the function "inline" ?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761834/defining-constructor-in-header-file-vs-implementation-cpp-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a *linker* error. The file which contains the definition of `myFunc` is not being compiled, or you are not linking to the library which exported it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an implementation for `myFunc`? Have you only **declared** `myFunc()` in the header and not defined it?

You can fix this by **defining** your function.

```
void myFunc(); // Declaration
void myFunc() {} // Definition
```

This error is caused because the the **symbol** that is `myFunc` has no **definition** and therefore cannot be **resolved** by the linker.

Answer (score 1):

You propably miss to provide the library / object file with `myFunc` to your linker.